# Symfony. Repository method. Bind the User in query parameter (queryBuilder)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem, I'm new in symfony 3.2
I want to query an object based on user's logged in. I heard I needed to inject users info? But how?

Repository

```
public function findAllActiveCategoryByUser(UserInterface $user)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('sc')
        ->andWhere('sc.company_id = :company')
        ->setParameter('company_id', $this->getUser->getCompany->getCompanyId)
        ->orderBy('sc.createdAt', 'ASC');
}
```

SubAgentType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
             ->add('category', EntityType::class, [
            'placeholder' => 'Choose Category',
            'class' => Sub_agent_category::class,
            'query_builder' => function (Sub_agent_categoryRepository $er) {
                return $er->findAllActiveCategoryByUser();

            },
            'constraints' => array(new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Category is required.')))
        ])
```

Comment: can you be a bit more specific ? Is that code from an EntityRepository ? you can easily get the currently logged in user in the controller and pass the object along to the Repository.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();

    $builder
        ->add('company', EntityType::class, [
            'placeholder' => 'Choose Company',
            'class' => Company::class,
            'query_builder' => function (CompanyRepository $er) {
                return $er->findAllActiveCompany($user);
            },
            'constraints' => array(new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Company is required.')))
        ])
}
```

**Repository:**

```
public function findAllActiveCategoryByUser(UserInterface $user)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('sc');
    $result = $qb->select('sc')
        ->where('sc.company_id = :company')
        ->setParameter('company', $this->getUser->getCompany->getCompanyId)
        ->orderBy('sc.createdAt', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery();
    return $result->getResult();
```

}

Comment: Hi this is close answer, but I have error., `must implement interface Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface, none given, called in ` Do you know how to solve it.

Comment: Hi ! Try `dump($user);die;`  or `var_dump($user);die;` before `$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('sc');`

Comment: Can you show me your Controller where call your `findAllActiveCategoryByUser()` method?

Comment: Hi im not using the query in controller, im using it on my form. Please see updated question

Comment: then can you show your `form` where you call this `method`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138100/discussion-between-imanali-mamadiev-and-jlacsonph).